# Python - checking if string path is valid using matrices and textfiles

Tags: python, file, matrix, graph

I'm in my first-year programming class for beginners, and we use Python to code. Last time, we've learnt about textfiles, graphs and adjacency matrices. I got stuck on one exercise and I really don't know where to begin in the first place...

Based on a graph that has been given to us, we've built an adjacency matrix. The exercise asks us to open a textfile, write different number strings inside, and write a code to test if these paths are valid on the graph or not using the matrix we've built (ex, 1245, 12345 are valid paths, 135 isn't).

I'm at a complete loss and really don't know how to tackle this. I took programming because I thought it'd be interesting (which it is), but I have no prior knowledge of it and it gets really hard for me sometimes to wrap my head around problems like these. Could you please give me a hint of what to do? Of course, I don't need the full answer (that'd be counter-productive), but I'd like at least know how to start...

Here's my matrix and my textfile if it can be of any help:

```
newfile = open("textexercise.txt", "r+")
newfile.write("12345\n")
newfile.write("1245\n")
newfile.write("15432\n")
newfile.write("35421\n")
newfile.write("512\n")
newfile.write("354\n")
newfile.write("135\n")
newfile.write("134\n")
newfile.write("415\n")
newfile.write("5234\n")


myList = []
myList.append([])
myList.append([])
myList.append([])
myList.append([])
myList.append([])
myList[0] = [False,True,False,False,True]
myList[1] = [True,False,True,True,False]
myList[2] = [False,True,False,True,True]
myList[3] = [False,True,True,False,True]
myList[4] = [True,False,True,True,False]
```

I apologise if it is a dumb question. I'm very new to all of this. Have a nice day!

Comment: As a starting point: what if you have more than 10 nodes in your graph?  Right now you can number them from 0 to 9, but when you add node 10, it looks just like nodes 1 and node 0 next to each other.  You should add commas or spaces to separate the nodes.

Comment: @James I'm not sure I understood your comment. There's only five nodes to my graph. Do you mean I should put commas in the strings of the file? If it was what you meant, we're not allowed to change the strings, so I don't think I can do that. If that wasn't what you meant, I apologise, I didn't get it.

Comment: With only 5 nodes, it is fine.  You need to use the adjacency matrix to check if a path exists between a pair of points.  Do you have a handle on how to do that?

Comment: Also, what format is the adjacency matrix in?  Can you use `numpy`?

Comment: @James: no, I can't use numpy, the way we've learnt to "build" matrices is under this list form shown above. I know how to read adjacency matrices, I just don't know how to make a code that'd test if one "path" in my file is correct given said matrix.

Comment: Could you add the adjacency matrix to the question?  It is stored as a list of 5 lists?

Comment: I did, it's the 2D list I've put at the end of the question. It's a first-year class so it's probably not the "classical" way to build matrices but it's the only way we've learnt so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the long conversation.  It took a while for me to understand what you had included in your code block.  Here is a snippet of code to help out.  The essence of the code is the following:

- Turn the path string into a list of indices from 0 to 4
- Create pairs of start and end nodes for each step of the path
- The first element of each step-pair is the row index, the second is the column index of the adjacency matrix.
- Check each step, and if it hits a `False` value, stop and return `False`

---

```
# define a function to text the path
def test_path(adj_m, path_str):
    # turn the node number into a list index.  need to 
    # subtract 1 from each element since python is zero-indexed
    path = [int(x)-1 for x in list(path_str.strip())]

    # create pairs of nodes uzing zip.  this will turn the path 0,1,2,4
    # into (0,1), (1,2), (2,4)
    for a,b in zip(path, path[1:]):
        # check the row and column of the adjacency matrix, stopping if
        # path is forbidden, return False
        if not adj_m[a][b]:
            return False
    # if the we make it through the entire for-loop, then all paths are
    # valid, return True
    return True
```